# Best Way to Test Boolean Values in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Looking to get some opinions here.

What is the best way to check boolean values with RSPEC I have seen it done a few different ways:

```
myvar.should == true
myvar.should be true
myvar.should be
```

Also I usually only care about the duck value, that is, if it evaluates to true / false then I don't care what its actual value is...

Comment: It looks like you know *how*, so what are you trying to figure out? Is there something that you don't like about the options you've provided?

Comment: Ya I guess I always drift between the above three and I don't really know what is the 'right' way to do it. I was hoping someone could explain why one option might be better than the others...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the difference between "== true" and "be(true)":

```
describe true do
  it { should be(true) }
  it { should be_true }
end

describe 'true' do
  it { should_not be(true) }
  it { should be_true }
end
```

Which basically means that if you only care if a value evaluates to true then you want to use == true

Comment: I didn't realize you could pass the value 'it' refers to on the describe line, I'd always used subject {} to set it. Cool.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the opposite logic:

```
expect([true, false]).to include myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my advise the best way is to add rspec_boolean to your Gemfile in the group :development, :test:

gem 'rspec_boolean'

And than use it like:

expect(val.is_something?).to be_boolean